# Reset React state before a render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-hooks, jsx

I'm building a web application that consumes TMDB Api. I have the following code that fetch all information about a TV Show

```
export const useShowInfoFetch = ({showId}) => {

  const [data, setData] = useState({})
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
  const [_error, _setError] = useState(false)

  const fetchShowInfo = useCallback(() => {
    setLoading(true)

    try {
      axios.get(getShowInfo(showId))
        .then(response => {
          setData(response.data)
        })
    } catch (error) {
      _setError(true)
    } finally {
      setLoading(false)
    }
  }, [showId])

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchShowInfo()
  }, [fetchShowInfo])

  return [data, loading, _error]
}
```

All the information fetched is displayed in page, that also has *Links* with **react-router-dom**. Those links goes to another tv show page.
The problem is that when I'm in a page with a tv show that has X amount of seasons and I click a tv show with less seasons, the seasons from the page I was are persisting for a little bit of time. So, when I fetch the information for each season I got a 404 in the page that has less seasons.

Here is a screenshot of the error

[image]

The orange circle is what it's displayed since I click the tv show with less seasons.
As you can see, the seasons from the previous page are persisting for a little time, and because The Alienist has only 2 seasons (not 9) I get the 404. You can also note that latter, the correct amount of seasons are displayed.

I've tried to add a cleanup method in the *useEffect* hook. Something like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetchShowInfo()
    
    return function cleanup() {
      setData({})
    }
  }, [fetchShowInfo])
```

But this did not work.

I know that I can handle that with a *catch* after the *then* Axios promise, but I want to figure out why this is happening and fix the issue with a good solution instead of avoiding it.

Any help is welcomed and I can share the repository with all the code if needed.

EDIT:

To display the similar movies I use another custom hook

```
export const useSimilarFetch = (elementType, elementId) => {

  const [similarElements, setSimilarElements] = useState({elements: []})
  const [similarLoading, setSimilarLoading] = useState(false)
  const [_error, _setError] = useState(false)

  const fetchSimilarElements = useCallback(async (endpoint) => {
    console.log(">>> fetching similar elements <<<")
    setSimilarLoading(true)

    try {
      await axios.get(endpoint)
        .then(response => {
          setSimilarElements(() => ({
            elements: [...response.data.results],
            currentPage: response.data.page,
            totalPages: response.data.total_pages
          }))
        })
    } catch (error) {
      _setError(true)
    } finally {
      setSimilarLoading(false)
    }
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchSimilarElements(getSimilar(elementType, elementId));
  }, [fetchSimilarElements, elementType, elementId])

  return [{similarElements, similarLoading, _error}, fetchSimilarElements]
}
```

Then, in my ShowInfoComponent I call all the needed hooks like this:

```
const {showId} = useParams()
const [data, loading, _error] = useShowInfoFetch({showId})
const [{similarElements, similarLoading}] = useSimilarFetch("tv", showId)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the time `showId` changes, `data` has to wait one additional render cycle, so `showId` is already used even though `data` has not yet been fetched. The UI relies on both `showId` and `data`, yet `data` depends on `showId`. One way to solve this could be having your UI to rely on `data` alone. What about the id? Add it to `data` for example. We merely want to avoid the desynchronization.

Something like this:

```
export const useShowInfoFetch = ({showId}) => {

  const [data, setData] = useState({})
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
  const [_error, _setError] = useState(false)

  const fetchShowInfo = useCallback(() => {
    setLoading(true)

    try {
      axios.get(getShowInfo(showId))
        .then(response => {
          setData({ id: showId, info: response.data})
        })
    } catch (error) {
      _setError(true)
    } finally {
      setLoading(false)
    }
  }, [showId])

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchShowInfo()
  }, [fetchShowInfo])

  return [data, loading, _error]
}
```

Then use `data.id` to build your links.
If  `response.data` already contains the id, then even better, use that.

That's just an example, of course but hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: data.id only retrieves 1 id, that belongs to the tv show id. To build my links I use another custom hooks _useSimilarFetch_ that retrieves the similar TV Show for an ID

Comment: I see. I wouldn’t mind seeing more of the code then. For now, I can just make assumptions.

Comment: I've updated my question. Also, this is the link to the repo: https://gitlab.com/lucas.distasi/react-tmdb/-/blob/master/src/components/show/ShowInfoComponent.jsx. Feel free to take a look if you want. I believe the issue it's somewhere near that component and the hooks that it's using. Thanks Sir.

Comment: Thank you. I've had a look. Can you tell me where the errors are occuring? Is it in `SeasonAccordionComponent`? If so, like I said, by the time showId changes, `seasons` which comes from `useShowInfoFetch` won't have been fetched yet.

Comment: Yes. SeasonAccordionComponent render a tab for each season. Because "The Alienist" has less season than "GOT", it throws an 404 error when fetching the information for a season (because it's trying to get the 9 seasons from GoT and it only has 2). I believe it's because what you say (seasons are fetched after the showid changes). I've no idea how to fetch the seasons before the showid

Comment: What I've been trying to tell you in my answer is, showId and seasons come from two different places, and seasons depends on showId, showId will be available first, then seasons. The idea was that all the props would come from one place, for example, where seasons come from. You could add the id into data if it's not already there and then call the component with it, something like this: `<SeasonAccordionComponent seasons={data.seasons} showId={data.showId} originalPoster={backdrop_path}/>`

Comment: This way, even if showId changes, the component will first wait for the `useShowInfoFetch` hook to return its value to display the information. The idea is to provide the whole thing AT THE SAME TIME to the `SeasonAccordionComponent`. Do you understand?

Comment: I understand. I've made those changes and seems it's working now! Many thanks Sir. You are a genius!

Comment: :) my pleasure!

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong but I believe you are not watching the correct value on the useEffect. You should be watching **showId** and not the function **fetchShowInfo**. That is:

```
 useEffect(() => {
  fetchShowInfo()
 }, [showId]) --> HERE
```

And as you are memoized the callback, if you are watching the wrong variable then you will get back the 'last answered'.